# Custom CreateUserWizard adding 2 fields

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-membership, createuserwizard

I am attempting to customise the CreateUserWizard by following it in my book, but when I come to reference them in code behind I get an error saying 'FieldName is not declared' for each field i'm adding, they are present in the page with the correct ID's, am I doing something wrong?

I am only trying to add a firstName and lastName field to the bottom of the CreateUserWizard and remove the need to a security question.

Markup:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                Sign Up for Your New Account</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                    ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                    ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                    AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." 
                                    ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." 
                                    ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="FirstName">First Name:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="FirstNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="FirstName" ErrorMessage="First name is required." 
                                    ToolTip="First name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer">Last Name:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="LastNameLabelRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="LastName" ErrorMessage="Last name is required." 
                                    ToolTip="Last name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                    Display="Dynamic" 
                                    ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match." 
                                    ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"></asp:CompareValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
            <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
            </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Code-behind:

```
Protected Sub CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim pc As ProfileCommon = New ProfileCommon()
    pc.Initialize(CreateUserWizard1.UserName.ToString(), True)

    pc.firstName = FirstName.Text
    pc.lastName = LastName.Text

    pc.Save()
End Sub
```

Comment: You also have an error. LastNameLabel should be associated with LastName control, not answer (at least in the code you posted, it throws an exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They wont be accessable directly like that. Use this code to get the values.

```
var fn = CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("FirstName");
var ln = CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("LastName");
```

Comment: oh, thanks, any reason why it isn't like that in my book? is there a way to makae it accessible the way I had it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. I've read many books that just had old or wrong code. The code i posted seems more like a hack but if you think about it, the controls are defined within another control so they wouldn't be exposed on your page level. It's most likely because it's within a contenttemplate. I bet if it wasn't in the contentemplate, you would be able to access them.

Comment: thanks for the info, yeah could well be correct about the master page. But i've used the code and it's now working fine...thanks again.